# Strange VC Linker Error LNK1107 that references link.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, linker

I am getting a really strange linker error appearing:

```
link.exe : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x270
```

But this is strange, because usually the error message tells you what object is invalid or corrupt. In other words, typically this error message looks something like this:

```
myDLL.dll : fatal error LNK1107: ....
```

However, in this case, the invalid object is the application itself (link.exe) that is running!

I've tried replacing the executable with another copy that I know is valid. Same error.

The command I am running is this:

```
../vendor/microsoft/msdev80_2005/VC/bin/link.exe /NOLOGO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LIB
PATH:../vendor/microsoft/msdev80_2005/VC/atlmfc/lib /LIBPATH:../vendor/microsoft
/msdev80_2005/VC/lib /LIBPATH:../vendor/microsoft/msdev80_2005/VC/PlatformSDK/Li
b /LIBPATH:lib/win32/dbg /OUT:bin/win32/dbg/bugshow.exe Advapi32.lib ws2_32.lib
bugshow/obj/win32/dbg/main.o libA.lib libB.lib libC.lib libD.lib
```

main.o is getting compiled using the following compiler directive:

```
../vendor/microsoft/msdev80_2005/VC/bin/cl.exe /nologo /X /w /EHsc -I../vendor/m
icrosoft/msdev80_2005/VC/atlmfc/include -I../vendor/microsoft/msdev80_2005/VC/in
clude -I../vendor/microsoft/msdev80_2005/VC/PlatformSDK/Include /D_WIN32 /DBOOST
_USE_WINDOWS_H /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LI
B /DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /Z7
/MTd /c -I../vendor/boost.org/boost/1.45.0/include /Fobugshow/obj/win32/dbg/main.o 
bugshow/main.cpp
```

Any ideas why link.exe would be failing like this?

**UPDATE:**

When I add the folder that link.exe resides in to my PATH, and then call link.exe without the path prefix, I get the following error instead:

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'link.exe'
```

Why is link.exe trying so desperately to open itself??!?!

Comment: Why did you tag this `visual-studio-2008` when you're running `msdev80_2005/VC/bin/cl.exe`?

Comment: Are you really running these manually from the command prompt, or is a tool running them for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem!

There is a nasty little ENVIRONMENT variable that the MSVC linker uses ([described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448630.aspx)) on Microsoft's MSDN page. It says:

```
LINK, if defined, prepends arguments in the command line.
```

My system had the environment variable `LINK` defined as `STATIC` by a recent application I installed. This caused link.exe to interpret the command-line instantiation of itself as follows:

```
STATIC link.exe /NOLOGO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE ...
```

In other words, `*argv[1]` which is usually the first command line parameter, was actually `link.exe`. It basically bumped all the arguments down by one offset. This in turn caused link.exe to try and interpret itself as its first input file!

Absolutely, unbelievably frustrating and hard to detect problem...

Comment: What is this "recent application" that you speak of?

Comment: @silico: its part of an in-house toolsuite that is used at the company I work for. I'll have to tell the developers about the conflict in causes! Still though, this issue caused by Microsoft's linker virtually inhibits someone from using a ENV var called 'LINK'. AND almost impossible to debug!

Comment: @J T: I have actually never came across this issue myself; that's why I ask. It's good to know, though.

Answer (score 0):

I read that it produces this error when you've included a header file (.h) in your Linker. I had this problem and solved it by removing the .h in Linker > Input > Addtl Dependencies